# R Equivalent of "end" in MatLab

Tags: r, matlab, dataframe

In Matlab, if I want to get a slice of a dataset starting from 100th row to the very last row, I can do something like `t2 = t1(100:end,:)`. I am just wondering if there is an equivalent way to do it in R, except using `dim()` function to get the number of rows first? I just want to avoid this extra step. Thanks!

Comment: `t1[100:nrow(t1), ]`

Comment: in short, no there is no such shortcut in base R. some packages have an equivalent, though, e.g. `.N` from `data.table`. PS its been so long since ive seen matlabs inexplicable use of parentheses (vs square brackets basically everywhere else in the world) to subset matrices... my eyes